# Latex. Figure reference doesn't work

Tags: cross-referencing, floats

Any idea why the figure referencing of the following code doesn't work ?

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\begin{figure}[h]
\floatbox[{\capbeside\thisfloatsetup{capbesideposition={right,top},capbesidewidth=4cm}}]{figure}[\FBwidth]
{\caption{A test figure with its caption side by side}\label{fig:tri}}
{\includegraphics[height=10cm]{triangulation}}
\end{figure}
```

"See figure \ref{tri}" is compiled as "See figure ??"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should simply use "See figure `\ref{fig:tri}`", the call to the reference `\ref{}` should use the same content as the label itself `\label{}`.